# SQL: How to perform PERCENTILE_CONT of group sum among groups?

Tags: sql, window-functions, partition, percentile, percentile-cont

Very simply, let's say I have want to SUM the total of a feature within a group.

So I partition over a window function:

```
SELECT sum(NumberOfPlayers) over (partition by sport) as SumOfSport
```

Great, this is good. Now.. I want to know the percentile of that sum among all the sums I just made.

A sport with 9 players, for example, among five sports, where it ranked 2nd of five, would be in the 40th percentile.

Let's start simple.. I want to know where the 20th percentile is.

`... PERCENTILE_CONT(0.2) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SumOfSport ASC) OVER (PARTITION BY NumberOfPlayers) AS AVGPV20`

But this fails. You cannot use a previous window function within the `SELECT`.

So how do we use PERCENTILE_CONT here without having to do a join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select sport, sum(NumberOfPlayers),
       percentile_cont(0.2) within group (order by   sum(NumberOfPlayers) asc) over () AS avgpv20
from t
group by sport;
```

Then `join` this result back in to your original query.

Trying to do the `percentile_cont()` without aggregating the data is going to be quite challenging -- because individual values are replicated.  It is simpler just to aggregate and `join` back in.

Comment: When I first ran this, it only gives the percentile _among the group's sum_. But there's only one SUM per group. So the percentile is the sum..